# MSSQL 2012 - Find rows that column contains following digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains a `varchar(50)` column.

Sometimes there are invalid values in this column. I'm now cleaning it and did a lot of good work using `regex` and `string manipulation functions`.

I now got stuck with values like this: **`123456789`** or **`5678`** or **`987654`**.

How can I retrieve all the rows that this column contains digits in a going up or down order?

Comment: There are not that many of them.  I would just generate them all.

Comment: There is no other way than listing them `like (1|12|123)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice simple solution. Inspired by @Larnu answer.

```
DECLARE @Pattern varchar(9) = '123456789';
```

DECLARE @RevPattern varchar(9) = '987654321';

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 YT     
WHERE charINDEX(YT.col1, @Pattern) > 0
   or charINDEX(YT.col1, @RevPattern) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I retrieve all the rows that this column contains digits in a
>   going up or down order?

For this, You can try something like,

```
select * from my_table
where isnumeric(my_column) = 1
order by CAST(my_column AS int);
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9fd9c/3)

Note: `ISNUMERIC` is not perfect. It will consider some characters as numeric too. You can read it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121225074805/http://www.sqlhacks.com/Retrieve/Isnumeric-problems)

Comment: Works, until you have values like `'.'` and `'$'`, etc. `SELECT ISNUMERIC('.'), ISNUMERIC('$')` returns 1 for both values.

Comment: @Larnu, Yea, I've added it in my answer.

Comment: Not working well. It returned 12456 . digit 3 is missing

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...? It's completely untested though:

```
DECLARE @Run varchar(9) = '123456789';

WITH Nums AS (
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1
    FROM Nums
    WHERE i + 1 <= 9),
Ranges AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Run, N1.I, N2.I) AS Run
    FROM Nums N1
         JOIN Nums N2 ON N2.I >= 4
                     AND N1.I + N2.I <= 10)
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS JOIN Ranges R --yes, I know this turns into an implicit JOIN 
                         --I just felt it was easier to display by using the WHERE
WHERE YT.YourColumn LIKE '%' + R.Run + '%'
   OR YT.YourColumn LIKE '%' + REVERSE(R.Run) + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just generate the sequences

```
with cte as 
( select i, i as nxt, i as num 
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(i)
  union all 
  select i, nxt + 1, num * 10 + nxt + 1 from cte  
  where nxt + 1 <= 9
)
select * from cte 
order by i, nxt;

with cte as 
( select i, i as nxt, cast(i as bigint) as num 
  from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) v(i)
  union all 
  select i, nxt - 1, num * 10 + nxt-1
  from cte  
  where nxt - 1 >= 0
)
select * from cte 
order by i, nxt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mod functions. Will need to make sure all your values are numeric first.

```
-- Mod calculation example
DECLARE @Number VARCHAR(100) = '123468'

SELECT
    Original = @Number,
    Length = LEN(@Number),
    Mod1 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 1 THEN @Number / 1 % 10 END,
    Mod2 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 2 THEN @Number / 10 % 10 END,
    Mod3 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 3 THEN @Number / 100 % 10 END,
    Mod4 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 4 THEN @Number / 1000 % 10 END,
    Mod5 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 5 THEN @Number / 100000 % 10 END,
    Mod6 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 6 THEN @Number / 1000000 % 10 END,
    Mod7 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 7 THEN @Number / 10000000 % 10 END,
    Mod8 = CASE WHEN LEN(@Number) >= 8 THEN @Number / 100000000 % 10 END


-- Table example
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Numbers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Numbers

CREATE TABLE #Numbers (numberString VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Numbers (numberString)
VALUES
    ('123456789'),
    ('915'),
    ('015463'),
    ('3468'),
    ('7654'),
    ('3210')


;WITH ModCalculations AS
(
    SELECT
        Original = numberString,
        Length = LEN(numberString),
        Mod1 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 1 THEN numberString / 1 % 10 END,
        Mod2 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 2 THEN numberString / 10 % 10 END,
        Mod3 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 3 THEN numberString / 100 % 10 END,
        Mod4 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 4 THEN numberString / 1000 % 10 END,
        Mod5 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 5 THEN numberString / 100000 % 10 END,
        Mod6 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 6 THEN numberString / 1000000 % 10 END,
        Mod7 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 7 THEN numberString / 10000000 % 10 END,
        Mod8 = CASE WHEN LEN(numberString) >= 8 THEN numberString / 100000000 % 10 END
    FROM
        #Numbers AS T
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ModCalculations AS T
WHERE
    (
        (
            T.Mod1 + 1 = T.Mod2 AND
            T.Mod2 + 1 = T.Mod3 AND
            T.Mod3 + 1 = T.Mod4 AND
            (T.Mod4 + 1 = T.Mod5 OR T.Mod4 * T.Mod5 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod5 + 1 = T.Mod6 OR T.Mod5 * T.Mod6 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod6 + 1 = T.Mod7 OR T.Mod6 * T.Mod7 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod7 + 1 = T.Mod8 OR T.Mod7 * T.Mod8 IS NULL)
        )
        OR
        (
            T.Mod1 - 1 = T.Mod2 AND
            T.Mod2 - 1 = T.Mod3 AND
            T.Mod3 - 1 = T.Mod4 AND
            (T.Mod4 - 1 = T.Mod5 OR T.Mod4 * T.Mod5 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod5 - 1 = T.Mod6 OR T.Mod5 * T.Mod6 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod6 - 1 = T.Mod7 OR T.Mod6 * T.Mod7 IS NULL) AND
            (T.Mod7 - 1 = T.Mod8 OR T.Mod7 * T.Mod8 IS NULL)
        )
    )
```